Algorithm to minimize the number of printing plates when printing sheets of stickers
I am working on an algorithm for optimizing the costs of a printing company by solving a problem they face. The problem is similar to knapsack problem but with a twist, instead of minimizing the number of containers to fit the content, we need to optimize the number of unique containers that we need to use. The problem is that the printing company first needs to design and develop printing plates which are then used for printing sheets. Printing sheets are cheap but printing plates are expensive so the company has to minimize the number of plates that they need to create inorder to achieve the desired outcome.
In simple terms, there are X different types of stickers that need to be printed in some quantity. Each printing plate can accomodate N stickers. We need an algorithm that can calculate the minimum amount of plates we will need inorder to print the given stickers (A printing plate can be used infinite times to print a sheet). A simple unoptimized approach to this is to create X printing plates and accomodate N number of stickers in each plate i.e if plate size is 10 and there are 2 different types of stickers and we need to print A(200) and B(300), we can simply create 2 plates, 1st one with 10 A stickers and second one with 10 B stickers and then we can print them according to required quantity (20 sheets for plate 1 and 30 sheets for plate 2). However, a better approach would be to use 1 plate with 4 A stickers and 6 B stickers and then print 50 sheets to achieve the required quantity.
When plate size = 10 and required quantities = {A: 200, B: 300}

Unoptimized Approach:

 _________               _________
|A|A|A|A|A| x 20        |B|B|B|B|B| x 30
|A|A|A|A|A|             |B|B|B|B|B|
 ---------               ---------

Optimized Approach:
 _________
|A|A|A|A|B| x 50
|B|B|B|B|B|
 ---------

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My first bruteforce approach to this problem was to sort the stickers by their required quantityand then calculate their ratios and assign them to a printing plate based on their ratios and then print them until the smallest quantity becomes 0 or negative (printing extra sheets can be a wastage but its not that big of a deal in small amounts). However, this didnt give an optimal answer and therefore, now i am stuck. Tried to search for similar problems but could'nt find any. Tried asking an LLM but it always answered with generic knapsack problem approach.

Can you throw away parts of sheets? Or does it need to add up exactly?

You need to somehow express the cost of printing extra sheets. Otherwise the solution is trivial - pack the "kinds" per plate greedily and you will always end up with ceiling(types_of_stickers/plate_size).
Edit: Or maybe that's what you actually want - is it okay to always aim for ceil(types_of_stickers/plate_size) and then just optimize the ratios of stickers?

@btilly Yes, you can throw away parts of sheet. I've mentioned it as wastage and its fine as long as its not too much.

@RafałDowgird We can assign values for plate_cost and sheet_cost if that can help the algorithm perform better but I am stuck on the core logic on how we can approach this problem. Let's say we assign plate_cost as 100 and sheet_cost as 1 (plate is 100 times more expensive than sheets), how will we approach this problem then?

@RafałDowgird The optimal answer would definitely be ceiling(sticker_types/plate_size) but we need to account for wastage aswell as the design of plate. If sticker_types is 11 and plate_size is 10, we must utilize the extra 9 slots in the 2nd plate for the stickers with the higher quantities. Similarly, if for example 5 sticker types require quantity of approx 200 and 5 sticker types require quantity of approx 400, it would be better to have 2 plates instead of mashing them into 1 and printing 400 sheets (resulting in a lot of wastage)

If you're not going to crisply define things like "account for wastage", then nobody can answer your question.  You can only optimize the output of one function, so you need to decide what that function is.

what are reasonable sizes of nr of different stickers, and nr of sheets?

@MattTimmermans If we define costs for both plates and sheets, what we can do is optimize the cost instead of optimizing 1 thing only. Otherwise the answer would be trivial as the comment above stated. Optimizing plates only would result in ceiling(types/size) and optimizing sheets only is a classic knapsack problem. The problem is figuring out the basic approach that should be taken even if we are accounting for both costs

@ChristianSloper For the problem i am trying to solve, the company is usually performing this for 20-30 clients at a time which means 20-30 different types of stickers. Number of sheets is dependent on plate_size, if plate_size is 10 then that means every sheet will have 10 stickers and we can divide total quantity of stickers required by plate size to figure that out. It also depends on the wastage due to plate design so if for example 1 plate has 10 stickers of same type and we only need 11 stickers made, we will still need 2 sheets even though it will result in a waste of 9 stickers

Have you considered using a integer programming library?  like Ortools or similar?

This seems like something a genetic algorithm could output a decent enough estimate for. You have StickersPerPlate, CostPerPlate, CostPerSheet, StickerQuantityArray as inputs. You'd need some custom transform functions (with restrictions, like every StickerQuantityIndex need s to appear at least once). You'd need to run the genetic algorithm with varying numbers of output plates maybe Ceil(Len(StickerQuantityIndex / StickersPerPlate) to double that. Output would be the Plates with indexes representing the kinds of stickers and the number of sheets each plate makes. The score function...

.. The score function would need to solve for the optimal number of Sheets to run for each Plate to make sure all of the StickerQuantities are satisfied.

@ChristianSloper I have no knowledge regarding what integer programming is and why is it used, i'll have to research about it to see where it can get me

It can be expressed as an integer programming problem to be solved by tools like OR-Tools, although the constraints of LP like:

fixed number of variables (F)
no multiplication of variables (M)

mean two things: 1. You have to presume the maximum number of plates because of (F) and 2. You cannot explicitly model "number of sheets printed from plate" to multiply by "number of slots on plate with sticker type t" because of (M).
The trick to model around this is to have a separate variable for each triple of {plate, slot, kind of sticker} with the value v meaning "I need v stickers of particular kind printed from this slot. For example the optimized approach from your question would be:
Slot:   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A      50 50 50 50  0  0  0  0  0  0
B       0  0  0  0 50 50 50 50 50 50

and the plate would have to print 50 sheets because that's the maximum over individual slots.
Obviously this requires some constraints to avoid trying to print multiple different kinds of stickers from a single slot. Fortunately this is expressible in integer programming.
Also in reality you print the same number of stickers from each slot. Fortunately this just means that for a particular plate you need to print m sheets from it where m is the maximum of the vars from all slots - the cost function has to account for this though.
Now for the trick to prevent same slot being used for different kind of stickers. The first part is to introduce a set of shadow integer variables, one for each v,  each having a value in the range [0..1].
Now if we add a set of constraints like v[p,s,k] < b[p,s,k] * 1000000 we express that a particular v can be non-zero if and only if the corresponding b is 1. Now we can just add a per-slot constraint that the sum of the b is at most 1, which in turn makes it possible to only one v be non zero for each slot in each plate.
Obviously there also need to be constraints expressing that the sum of vs over all plates and slots for each kind of sticker produces the required number of stickers but this is straightforward.
For the objective function we need number of used plates, which again can be solved with a "boolean" type of variable one for each plate.
I have coded a PoC for this using OR-tools and it seems to work, although three plates and [20000, 500, 500] for stickers takes 8 seconds to produce first plate with A*10 printed 1600 times, second one with A*8, B,C printed 500 times. On larger instances it seems to quickly converge on the optimal or near-optimal solution but takes forever to "prove" it's optimal.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is NP-hard, so this is likely the best that can be done.

Your answer looks pretty solid from what i could grasp. I will have to research about integer programming and OR tools before i can actually implement a solution but thanks for taking out the time for this. Highly appreciated!

How to make the model account for the extra stickers that it is printing due to the constraint of printing the same number of stickers in each slot? I have added an additional constraint that the print count should not exceed the required_count+max_wastage and should not be less than required_count but due to this, the model doesn't optimize the print count even when it can like in your example, sometimes it gives B(550) and C(550) because it is allowed for 10% wastage.

I think the easiest way is through the objective function. Just directly minimize the sum of costs of the plates used (multiplied by plate cost), plus the additional cost of sheets printed.
This doesn't explicitly treat wastage but if you minimize the number of sheets printed you will minimize wastage.

@RafałDowgird Makes sense. Instead of minimizing plates, i should minimize cost i.e plate_countplate_cost + sheet_countsheet_cost

Yes, for this you probably need to introduce another set of per-plate variables to reflect the number of sheets, which is the per-plate maximum of the v-variables.

To help others looking for the code to solve a similar problem, I have managed to implement the solution to this problem thanks to the accepted answer. Here is the code.
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def solve_sticker_problem(
    num_slots,
    required_stickers,
    max_sheets_per_plate,
    max_wastage_ratio,
):
    # Initialize the solver
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SAT")

    if not solver:
        return None

    num_sticker_types = len(required_stickers)
    max_plates = (
        num_sticker_types  # We will presume max plates to be equal to kinds of stickers
    )

    # Decision variables
    # v[p, s, t] - number of stickers of type t in slot s on plate p
    v = {}
    # b[p, s, t] - binary variable if slot s on plate p is used for sticker type t
    b = {}
    # u[p] - binary variable if plate p is used
    u = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, f"u[{p}]") for p in range(max_plates)]

    for p in range(max_plates):
        for s in range(num_slots):
            for t in range(num_sticker_types):
                v[p, s, t] = solver.IntVar(0, solver.infinity(), f"v[{p},{s},{t}]")
                b[p, s, t] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, f"b[{p},{s},{t}]")

    # Constraints
    # 1. Each slot on each plate can be used for at most one type of sticker
    for p in range(max_plates):
        for s in range(num_slots):
            solver.Add(sum(b[p, s, t] for t in range(num_sticker_types)) == 1)
            for t in range(num_sticker_types):
                solver.Add(v[p, s, t] <= b[p, s, t] * max_sheets_per_plate)

    # 2. Sum of stickers of each type over all plates and slots should meet the required count
    for t in range(num_sticker_types):
        sumOfStickers = sum(
            v[p, s, t] for p in range(max_plates) for s in range(num_slots)
        )
        solver.Add(sumOfStickers >= required_stickers[t])
        solver.Add(
            sumOfStickers
            <= required_stickers[t] + (required_stickers[t] * max_wastage_ratio)
        )

    # 3. If a plate is used, it should be counted
    for p in range(max_plates):
        for t in range(num_sticker_types):
            for s in range(num_slots):
                solver.Add(v[p, s, t] <= u[p] * max_sheets_per_plate)

    # 4. Use same number of stickers for every slot in a plate
    for p in range(max_plates):
        for s in range(num_slots - 1):
            solver.Add(
                sum(v[p, s, t] for t in range(num_sticker_types))
                == sum(v[p, s + 1, t] for t in range(num_sticker_types))
            )

    # Objective: Minimize the number of plates used
    solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(u[p] for p in range(max_plates)))

    # Solve the problem
    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print("Solution:")
        for p in range(max_plates):
            if u[p].solution_value() == 1:
                prints = 0
                slots: dict[str, int] = {}
                for s in range(num_slots):
                    for t in range(num_sticker_types):
                        if b[p, s, t].solution_value() == 1:
                            slots[f"Type{t}"] = slots.get(f"Type{t}", 0) + 1
                            prints = v[p, s, t].solution_value()
                print(f"Plate {p} ({prints} sheets): {slots}")


# Example usage
num_slots = 10  # Number of slots per plate
required_stickers = [20000, 500, 500]  # Number of required stickers for each type
max_sheets_per_plate = 1000000  # Maximum sheets you can print from a plate
max_waste_percent = 0  # Percentage of max allowed wastage with respect to required stickers. Set to 0 to avoid wastage


solve_sticker_problem(
    num_slots,
    required_stickers,
    max_sheets_per_plate,
    max_waste_percent / 100,
)

Output:
Solution:
Plate 1 (500.0 sheets): {'Type2': 1, 'Type0': 8, 'Type1': 1}
Plate 2 (1600.0 sheets): {'Type0': 10}

Note: Time increases exponentially as the number of sticker types increase. You can increase wastage to reduce time taken. Any optimizations that can be done here are welcome as i am new to Integer Programming and OR-tools
